# Mysql like Query in elastic search

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I am working on elastic search for my current project, Need to implement like query in elastic search, getting wrong results, if i select location as Hyderabad getting correct results, but if i select New Delhi as my location getting wrong results like, New York, New jersey like, but i need exact result of New Delhi Only. And my Code as follows

```
$query = array(
    "query" => array(
        "filtered" => array(
            "query" => array("match_all" => array()),
            "query" => ($headerLocation != 'worldwide') ? array("match" => array('location' => $headerLocation)) : null,
            "filter" => array("bool" => array(
                    'must' => array(array('term' => array('user_type' => 'v')),
                        array('term' => array('status' => 'a'))),
                    'must_not' => array(
                        array('term' => array('subscription_type' => 'n')),
                    )
                ))
        )));
```

Thanks in advance, please help me out with this situation

Comment: you've got two `query` keys in the `filtered` array - the second query will trash/overwrite the first one.

Comment: can you please suggest me, where i have to change, and i also used, 
"should" => array( (!empty($headerLocation)) ? array("match" => array('location' => trim($headerLocation))) : null) used in filter

Comment: Take a look at [Combining Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html) in the ElasticSearch docs. You need to use a `bool` query to combine your queries.